# can't remove css defined table style for specific table in html

Tags: html, css

I'd like to remove the css from a single table in a page where all other tables are defined with css (and need to be). How can i circumvent the css rules for a specific single table for an html/php page?

Comment: The good thing about CSS is you can write a rule for that specific table, reference it by ID or class, and it will override the base style.

Comment: Hm, i wrote in css table#table{} and set the html to <table id="table"> and that didn't change output

Comment: its usually a bad practice to "unstyle" in CSS. define a style for the majority of your table as a class and mark-up those tables with that class. Define your alternate style as a class and mark-up your alternate table with that class.

Comment: You should be able to write `#table{}` or even `.table{}` and have some sort of impact. Are you certain you were not caching the style sheet? Might want to inspect your element and see what styles are being applied, what are being canceled out.

Comment: good point. caching has been an issue in this project because maybe the server doesn't update files even when i change them. I'm not sure why, but even when i had deleted browser cache, files that had been changed still looked like the old ones ( could tell from edited images )

Answer (score 1):

you can  check out how the css rules define in your page

```
if the rule defined like: '.targetTable'{} (by class) or '#tableId'{} (by id)

it would be easy to remove the css rule by changing the table class/id on html code

else if it defined like: 'table{}' (by object)
```

**Method 1**:use jquery to reset the table(which you want to use other style) css

**Method 2**:change the css rule by using class or id selector

Answer (score 1):

Given your defaults:

```
table {
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    border: 1px solid
}
```

When you want to have one table that goes against that rule, you could just add a css class to that instance and override the defaults:

```
<table><tr><td>Default Style</td></tr></table>
<table class="i-am-special"><tr><td>Special Style</td></tr></table>
```

Just use this css:

```
table.i-am-special {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px dotted;
}
```

You can reset/adjust as many or as little properties as you like in your "i-am-special" class.

Note also that it doesn't have to be "table.i-am-special" if the style can be applied to other things, that's just an example.